# create provider to show / hide a loading and use it in the component

Tags: angular

I'm using ionic 3.. and in my file called `services.ts` I have these 2 functions to show(`createLoader`) / hide (`cerrarLoading`) my `loading`.

```
.
.
@Injectable()
 export class ServicesProvider {
 loading: any;
.
.
}
constructor(
 public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
) {}

createLoader(message: string = MESSAGES.loading.message) {
  this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: message
  });
  this.loading.present();
}
//close loading
cerrarLoading() {
    this.loading.dismiss();
}
```

in my component:

```
constructor(
  public ServicesProvider: ServicesProvider,
) {
  setTimeout(function(){
  this.ServicesProvider.createLoader();
  },10000)
  setTimeout(function(){
    this.ServicesProvider.cerrarLoader();
  },15000)
}
```

I pretend with that, show it before consuming a web service, and remove it when I have an answer to the request. before these lines, I have already created `createLoader` and works, and I suspect that after using it (in the code I have set, for the first time I would use `cerrarLoader()`), I am getting these errors.

I'm getting this error:
[image]

Comment: Stop using anonymous functions. Use arrow functions: `setTimeout(() =>   this.ServicesProvider.createLoader())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @JBNizet it Works!! why?? what is the diference?? is the same...no?

Comment: Well, read the link of the duplicate I posted. No, it's not the same. One doesn't bind the function to this, and the other does.

Comment: Change the `loading: any;` to `loading: Loading;` and update the import statement to `import {Loading, LoadingController} from "ionic-angular";`